# Homotopy Notation

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy $\Leftarrow$ Wikipedia's definition of homotopy can be found at this link. I'll restate it anyway though:

A **homotopy** between two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ is a continuous function $H:X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$

**Example** For $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ and $g(x)=(x,e^x)$, then the map $H: \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $H(x,t) = (x,(1-t)x^3+te^x)$ is a homotopy between them.

My question pertains to the example. When we say $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ and $g(x)=(x,e^x)$, what exactly is meant here? Is the image of $f$ for all $x \in X$ a collection of *ordered pairs* $(x,x^3)$ and ordered pairs for $g$ as well?

I guess I'm just confused because I don't understand what the objects in the image of the function look like. To me, they sound like collections of 2-tuples.

Comment: $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ indicates that the values of $f$ and $g$ are ordered pairs of real numbers.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the collection of ordered pairs. But is this any different from saying $f(x)=x^3?$ And if so, how are they different?

Comment: $f(x)=x^3$ is a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R.$ $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ is not.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^3$ then the values of $f$ would be just real numbers (namely $x^3$), not ordered pairs.

Comment: So if it's not a function, what is it then?

Comment: What is not a function? Everything here so far is a function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You said $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ is not a function. What is it then?

Comment: No I said it is not a function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$

Comment: I see what you're saying now. But if you graphed $f(x)=x^3$ point by point and if you graphed $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ point by point, what would be the difference (besides the codomain)?

Comment: The graph points of $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ are triples, $(x,x,x^3).$ [Technically, they are of the form $(x,(x,x^3)),$ but these are essentially the same.]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122898/discussion-between-emily-burkenhamen-and-thomas-andrews).

Answer (score 1):

The image points  of the functions $f$ and $g$ are points in $\Bbb R^2$, so pairs of reals.

That's what $f,g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ means: $x \in \Bbb R$ goes in and, say, $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ comes out, which is indeed a pair of reals. The image of $f$, i.e. $f[\Bbb R]$, which is the set of all values, is equal to the *graph* of $f'(x)=x^3$ which is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. But $f'$ is a different function (it has values that are not pairs but just real numbers), but is related to $f$, in this special case.